# ListView OnItemClickListener Song

Tags: java, arrays

I've created a ListView (myList). By pressing on one of the items on the ListView, the app is supposed to direct the user to the PlaySongActivity page. 
I used a searchById function to try to match the ID of the song and the song in my database.( get ID of the song and match the song ID in database to play the same song) However, my teacher told me I am searching by the ID of the ListView, not the song.

So is there any way I can either search by the song title or possibly add an ID to each item in the ListView?

I'm a beginner in coding and have searched for hours and found no solution on the internet :(

```
private SongCollection mySongCollection = new SongCollection();

myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(SearchSong.this, PlaySongActivity.class);

                String resourceId = AppUtil.getResourceId(SearchSong.this, myList);
                Song selectedSong = mySongCollection.searchById(resourceId);
                AppUtil.popMessage(SearchSong.this, "Streaming music: " + selectedSong.getTitle());

                intent.putExtra("id", selectedSong.getId());
                intent.putExtra("title", selectedSong.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("artiste", selectedSong.getArtiste());
                intent.putExtra("fileLink", selectedSong.getFileLink());
                intent.putExtra("coverArt", selectedSong.getCoverArt());

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

SongCollection.class codes

```
    package com.example.musix;

public class SongCollection {
    private Song[] allSongs = new Song[9];
    public SongCollection (){
        prepareSongs();
    }
    private void prepareSongs(){
        Song theWayYouLookTonight = new Song ("S1001", "The Way You Look Tonight", "Michael Buble", "a5b8972e764025020625bbf9c1c2bbb06e394a60?cid=2afe87a64b0042dabf51f37318616965", 4.66, "michael_buble_collection");
        Song billiejean = new Song ("S1002", "Billie Jean", "Michael Jackson", "4eb779428d40d579f14d12a9daf98fc66c7d0be4?cid=2afe87a64b0042dabf51f37318616965", 4.9, "billie_jean");
        Song somethingJustLikeThis = new Song("S1003", "Something Just Like This","The Chainsmokers","499eefd42a24ec562c464bd7acfad7ed41eb9179?cid=2afe87a64b0042dabf51f37318616965", 4.13, "something_just_like_this");
        Song southOfTheBorder = new Song("S1004", "South of the Border","Ed Sheeran","7b43dd0c94b0af0c0401381a683d2f4833180ba3?cid=2afe87a64b0042dabf51f37318616965", 3.41, "south_of_the_border");
        Song oldTownRoad = new Song("S1005", "Old Town Road","Lil Nas X","3bc62106123fcafad475271e72e74cd7f519ab83?cid=2afe87a64b0042dabf51f37318616965", 1.9, "old_town_road");
        Song noGuidance = new Song("S1006", "No Guidance", "Chris Brown", "7c3bc7b4d1741a001463b570fe29f922d9c42bd6?cid=2afe87a64b0042dabf51f37318616965", 4.34, "no_guidance");
        Song closer = new Song("S1007", "Closer", "The Chainsmokers", "8d3df1c64907cb183bff5a127b1525b530992afb?cid=2afe87a64b0042dabf51f37318616965", 4.08, "closer");
        Song sideface = new Song("S1008", "側臉", "于果", "c8cc891a7cacb36857ea15c8fcfc4da6e4b1583d?cid=2afe87a64b0042dabf51f37318616965", 3.63, "sideface");
        Song kebukeyi = new Song("S1009", "可不可以", "张紫豪", "2d790215acf7c4e6c5e093255b94a936064f75ed?cid=2afe87a64b0042dabf51f37318616965", 4.01, "kebukeyi");

        allSongs[0]= theWayYouLookTonight;
        allSongs[1]= billiejean;
        allSongs[2]= somethingJustLikeThis;
        allSongs[3]= southOfTheBorder;
        allSongs[4]= oldTownRoad;
        allSongs[5]= noGuidance;
        allSongs[6]= closer;
        allSongs[7]= sideface;
        allSongs[8]= kebukeyi;
    }
    public Song searchById (String id){
        Song selectedSong = null;
        for(int index=0; index<allSongs.length; index++){
            selectedSong = allSongs[index];
            if(selectedSong.getId().equals(id)){
                return selectedSong;
            }
        }
        return selectedSong;
    }
    //create a method to retrieve the next song
    public Song getNextSong(String currentSongId){
        Song nextSong = null;
        for(int x = 0; x < allSongs.length; x++){
            String tempSongId = allSongs[x].getId();
            if(tempSongId.equals(currentSongId) && (x < allSongs.length -1)){
                nextSong = allSongs[x+1];
                break;
            }
        }
        return nextSong;
    }
    //create a method to retrieve the previous song
    public Song getPrevSong(String currentSongId){
        Song PrevSong = null;
        for(int x = 0; x < allSongs.length; x++){
            String tempSongId = allSongs[x].getId();
            if(tempSongId.equals(currentSongId) && (x > 0)){
                PrevSong = allSongs[x-1];
                break;
            }
        }
        return PrevSong;
    }
    //create a method  to get random song
    public Song getRandomSong(){
        Song randomSong = null;

        int max = 2;
        int min = 0;
        int randomNum = (int)(Math.random()*4);

        randomSong = allSongs[randomNum];
        return randomSong;
    }
}
```

Song.class codes

```
    package com.example.musix;

public class Song {
    //private attributes are hidden from other classes/files
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String artiste;
    private String fileLink;
    private double songLength;
    private String coverArt;

    public Song(String _id, String _title, String _artiste, String _fileLink, double _songLength, String _coverArt){
        this.id = _id;
        this.title = _title;
        this.artiste = _artiste;
        this.fileLink = _fileLink;
        this.songLength = _songLength;
        this.coverArt = _coverArt;
    }
    //encapsulation
    //SET methods for setting/changing of the values of the attributes

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setArtiste(String artiste) {
        this.artiste = artiste;
    }

    public void setFileLink(String fileLink) {
        this.fileLink = fileLink;
    }

    public void setSongLength(double songLength) {
        this.songLength = songLength;
    }

    public void setCoverArt(String coverArt) {
        this.coverArt = coverArt;
    }
    //GET methods allows us to retrieve values of the attributes

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public String getArtiste() {
        return this.artiste;
    }

    public String getFileLink() {
        return this.fileLink;
    }

    public double getSongLength() {
        return this.songLength;
    }

    public String getCoverArt() {
        return this.coverArt;
    }
}
```

codes for getResourceId

```
public final class AppUtil
{
    public static void popMessage(Context context, String message)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public static String getResourceId(Context context, View view)
    {
        String id = context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.getId());

        return id;
    }
```

Comment: What are you storing the song ID in?

Comment: in my song.class file

Comment: Oh ok, sorry about that because I still can't fix the error and I am supposed to hand it up tomorrow :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String resourceId = AppUtil.getResourceId(SearchSong.this, myList);
 Song selectedSong = mySongCollection.searchById(resourceId);
```

resourceId is going to be the id of the element of the list view (eg. first element id = 0, 2nd id = 1 and so on).

```
public Song searchById (String id){
        Song selectedSong = null;
        for(int index=0; index<allSongs.length; index++){
            selectedSong = allSongs[index];
            if(selectedSong.getId().equals(id)){
            return selectedSong;
        }
    }
    return selectedSong;
}
```

Should be:

```
public Song searchById (String id){
        //we are returning the song selected by the index of its Arrays
        Song selectedSong = allSongs[Integer.parseInt(id)];

    return selectedSong;
}
```

Why?:

Your returning the actual songid, but in

```
 Song selectedSong = mySongCollection.searchById(resourceId); <-- resourceId is already the Id stored in the database and not the index of mySongCollection.
 intent.putExtra("id", selectedSong.getId());
```

you are using already the actuals song id. This doesen't make sense as you can already identify the actual song.
So either apply these changes or change this line:

```
intent.putExtra("id", resourceId);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. When I change to    intent.putExtra("id", Integer.parseInt(resourceId));          the app crashes.  The other one where i change my searchById method also doesn't work. When i click on the item in listview, it goes to the last song i inputted in the database.

Comment: it still didn't work it goes to the last song for every song in the list view that i clicked. Is there anyway to give ID for the items in the listview?

Comment: by changing it to       Song selectedSong = allSongs[Integer.parseInt(id)];                   the app now crashes once i try to search something

Comment: Right now im like finding songId using listview Id so i think i need to change it so that i find songid using item Id in listview. But im not sure how to give id for the items in listview

Comment: can u do System.out.println(id) right above the line selectedSong = ..., it should print out the position of the object clicked in the list

Comment: erm, sorry but where do i see the print out

Comment: how are you running your app? Normaly there is a console window at the bottom of Android Studio, it might be a tab window so you need to click to focus it - also your app need to be started in debug mode, so dont click the green arrow but the little bug icon

Comment: It gives this error though      "Error running 'SearchSong': The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter"

Comment: im sorry, havent been to android lately, should be Log.d("myTag", id); This means that it is logged (printed to the debug console) when i n debug mode. The error is going to be printed as well but in the lines above your log function should log the value that is put into the function when you click on a song

Comment: Nope it didn't show anything. The error just popped up at the bottom right and it didn't run. If it is ok with you do u mind to do a share screen with me would be easier to fix the error

Comment: for clearance: the problem was that the return of AppUtil function wasn't the position but the object itself, so parsing didn't worked. We created a position integer by adding int listPosition = myList.getPositionForView(view);